# Define @Type in orm.xml (Spring Data / JPA 2.1 /Hibernate 5.3.7/Postgresql)?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jsonb

We need to perform CRUD operations on an object in Postgresql that has a jsonb field. I understand that we can create a user type and annotate them with @Type(type = "jsonb") in the model. However, we want to define mapping of meta data in orm.xml instead of annotations. We have tried to use a converter as well but still have no success. Is there a possibility to achieve this with orm.xml and how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Type is not part of JPA specification. It is Hibernate specific.

Alternative to JPA annotation is orm.xml.

Alternative for Hibernate annotation is hbm.xml - hibernate mapping file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="" table="">
        <id></id>
        <property>
            <type name="">
            </type>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks. We could try that approach as well. We are currently using the named native query with casting in orm.xml to use jsonb for now.